# How to make GraphQL query for YAML Markdown authors in Gridsome blog

Tags: vue.js, graphql, gridsome

I built a blog using Gridsome and so far everything is going fine. To create new post I simple create a new Markdown file inside a folder `Post` and it is automatically rendered on the front end. The front end displays a basic page `Blog.vue` with pagination which displays each post's title, author, date, clickable and auto generated tags, and also has a "read more" button which, when clicked, will bring the user to `Post.vue` , which displays the blog post and its related content. I am using graphQL to display each post and its content, as well as the links using `<page-query>` ( I wont post it here because I am not sure its relevant ).

Each post has a markdown file, and within the YAML header of each .md file I am able to put `tags` which function like twitter hashtags in my Vue App. When clicked, the user is directed to a page which displays *"All post tagged { tag name }"*. This is done by placing my Tag.vue inside of my `templates` folder and using the following query on the page.

also using...

`Tags { id 
        path 
        }`

.. in the `<page-query>` in my Blog.vue file

Here is the `<page-query>` I am using to get all post with a specific tag.

```
<page-query>
query ($id: String!){
  tag (id: $id) {
    title
    belongsTo {
      edges {
        node {
          ... on Post {
           id
        title
        excerpt
        date (format: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
        tags {
          id
          path
        }
        timeToRead
        path
        cover_image(width: 600, height:300, quality: 90, blur: 1)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</page-query>
```

**Here is my Tag.Vue**

```
<h1 style="color: white">Posts tagged #{{ $page.tag.title }}</h1>
    <article v-for="edge in $page.tag.belongsTo.edges" :key="edge.node.id">
      <div class="postContainer">
        <g-image :src="edge.node.cover_image" style="width: 100% ; padding-top: 15px;"></g-image>
        <h2>{{ edge.node.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ edge.node.excerpt }}</p>
        <p>Posted {{ edge.node.date }} - {{ edge.node.timeToRead }} min read</p>
        <!-- <div v-html="edge.node.content"></div> -->
        <div class="div1">
          <g-link
            class="span"
            style="padding: .5em ; background-color: #091A28"
            v-for="tag in edge.node.tags"
            :to="tag.path"
            :key="tag.id"
          >{{ tag.id }}</g-link>
          <br />
          <div class="readMore">
            <g-link :to="edge.node.path" class="gLinkPost">Read More</g-link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
```

I am trying to do something very similar using the YAML header variable "author:" , however I am having trouble and admittedly don't know exactly where to start.

I attempted to add a `Authors.vue` folder within my templates, and make a similar `<page-query>` , but I was not able to get that to work, but I think I might be on the right track.

I would prefer to have a **"Authors"** page which simply displays a styled list of authors and when clicked, will display all the users post, as well as allow the user to click the the authors name on a blog post and will direct to this **"Authors"** page.

Here is my structure for better reference.

[image]

Thanks for taking the time to reading. Thank you in advance for your responses.